# to maintain variable value in double datatype using .net

Tags: vb.net, datatable

Datatable contain some values like 0.0,10000.00,54678.94 .  am getting that values using for loop and store it in a variable in double datatype. i want to add these nos and store it in a variable.
each time variable value changed.

```
 for loop

   Dim ds5 As dataset1.pro_dtsumDataTable = TA5.GetData(TextBox1.Text, users)

   If (ds5.Rows.Count > 0) Then 
   Dim y As Double
   y = Double.Parse(ds5(0)("sum(fld_primary)").ToString())
   Dim y1 As Double
   y1 = 0 + y
   End If
  Next
```

first time y1=0.0
next time the value of y1 is not added to previous value.
i want the result y1=64679.34
am new to vb.net. please help to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for loop
   Dim ds5 As dataset1.pro_dtsumDataTable = TA5.GetData(TextBox1.Text, users)
   If (ds5.Rows.Count > 0) Then 
   Dim y As Double
   y = Double.Parse(ds5(0)("sum(fld_primary)").ToString())
   Dim y1 As Double
   y1 += 0 + y
   End If
  Next
```

You keep assigning y to y1. I think what you want to do is `increment` the value. eg

```
y1 += 0 + y
```

The += is the same as:

```
y1 = y1 + 0 + y
```

Comment: @Amulraj happy to help, there is a holo checkbox you can tick next to answers in [so], this will give you a couple of points.